# WinUI 3 DataGrid - how to share DataGrid.Columns definitions

Tags: datagrid, winui-3, windows-community-toolkit

In WinUI 3, I want to create two `DataGrid`s on a page with the same column definitions.  Essentially two of the following with different `ItemsSource` values but referencing data of the same type.  (And with 20+ columns, hence my interest in only defining the columns in one place.)

```
<controls:DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                   ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.Things}">
    <controls:DataGrid.Columns>
        <controls:DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
        <controls:DataGridTextColumn Header="Description" Binding="{Binding Description}"/>
    </controls:DataGrid.Columns>
</controls:DataGrid>
```

I have tried creating a `Page.Resource` for a template, along these lines:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="test">
        <controls:DataGrid>
            <controls:DataGrid.Columns>
                <controls:DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
                <controls:DataGridTextColumn Header="Description" Binding="{Binding Description}"/>
            </controls:DataGrid.Columns>
        </controls:DataGrid>
    </ControlTemplate>
</Page.Resources>
```

referencing it as follows (the only place I could find to reference it was the `Template` attribute. and that requires a reference to a `ControlTemplate`):

```
<controls:DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                   ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.Things}"
                    Template="{StaticResource test}">
</controls:DataGrid>
```

With this in place, the `DataGrid` shows the column headers, but no data.

What resource needs to be created and how is it to be referenced?